# jQuery DateBox loads slowly on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, gwt, datebox

I am using jQuery DateBox on my gwt project like this:

at my gwt.xml ui file I have input

```
<input type="text" ui:field="date" class="{resources.style.bottomSpacer}"
       data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"datebox", "useFocus": true, 
       "useNewStyle":true, "themeHeader": "b", "themeButton": "b", "themeInput": "c"}' />
```

When opening the datebox on clicking the input element on tablet, it is reported to load very slowly.

What may be causing it? Maybe some javascript gets loaded only after click and it loads the js libraries on fly?

Comment: Ok can provide us demo?

Comment: Have you tried to use GWTQuery? https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Comment: What here is different to http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/mode/slidebox.html demo site, is that I use different themes and demo only defaults. I will see what else is different and try that way to find the reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the `data-options` field and found out that using only one theme and disabling animation made the element much faster even on PC. At least I could see the difference on my fast PC. So, on tablet the difference may be even bigger.

Here is the `data-options` when changed:

```
"mode":"datebox", "useFocus": true, "useNewStyle":true, "useAnimation" : false, "themeHeader": "b", "themeButton": "b", "themeInput": "b"
```

So, there all theme related is with `b` and the `useanimation` thing is new.